# What is the best approach for printing a UserControl or a Window without blocking the UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, printing

I have bound the required data in my `UserControl`. This `UserControl` is the `Print Layout` of what I want to print. Great, now I can print it using `PrintVisual`.

```
private async void Print(){
    await Task.Run(() => {
        var printerName = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultPrinterName; //The Name of the Printer is stored on the Properties Settings.
        PrintDialog pd = new(){
            PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), printerName)
        };
        pd.PrintVisual(PrintLayout, "Print Job Description");
    });
}

... 
await Print(); //Call the async method to Print.
```

The above code will work. However, it will block the UI and I wouldn't say I like it.

I was thinking of converting the layout into an `image` and then printing it using `PrintDocument`. But then the quality won't be that good and I will need to handle the size. In my case, whatever the size of the layout should be the output. I am also thinking of converting the layout into `XPS` file or `PDF` and then maybe printing it using `PrintDocument` too but I'm not sure yet since this will require another IO processing and could lead to performance issues.

What could be the best approach here?

Comment: It looks like you are silently printing your UserControl. Anyway, between XPS and PDF conversion, it would be best to use XPS to avoid using any third-party library for PDF.

Comment: If performance issue, you mean delayed because of RAW, you can always use Async/Wait. Just add a Label Status or probably a progress in the UI while performing the conversion.

Comment: What is `PrintLayout`?

Comment: _"However, it will block the UI and I wouldn't say I like it."_ - Your code **won't** "block" the UI thread because you're using `await` - so **exactly** what undesirable behaviour are you experiencing?

Comment: _"In my case, whatever the size of the layout should be the output"_ <-- This is impossible: on-screen visuals in WPF are sized using device-independent pixels, whereas things that are printed to paper (or otherwise have a physical size) are sized in mm (or inches, or points) - you need to specify the ratio between screen-pixels and physical size (aka DPI, aka PPI). The default will be something like 96dpi.

Comment: @Dai as stated, the PrintLayout is the UserControl.

Comment: @Dai Wrong, regardless of using `Async/Await`, it will still block the UI the moment it reached the `PrintDialog.PrintVisual(Visual,Description)`. Try the code and see it for yourself.

Comment: @Dai Wrong again regarding the size. Right now, the above code is giving me an output of the correct size of the `PrintLayout`. It is not actually impossible.

Comment: @Bolomeo The “correct size” you’re referring to would be the aspect-ratio of the `Visual` combined with the default DPI setting as you haven’t overridden it. If you change your code to use a real-life low-resolution printer (e.g. cheap HP/Canon inkjet) then you’ll see what I’m referring to.

Comment: @Bolomeo I’ll concede you’re right about it blocking the UI thread - there’s some ugly gubbins in WPF that forces the rendering on the main scheduler. As it is, I don’t have a solution.

Comment: @Polar Very much appreciated your suggestion. And yes, I want to silently print the UserControl without showing any dialog. Anyway, would it be fine to elaborate the conversion to xps? I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Dai I've been trying to change my resolution, and dpi scaling and print the layout for almost two hours now just to generate what you said regarding the size but still giving me the correct output. I also tried to print in a thermal printer but still the same. I don't really know if you are right because I don't have an old printer but regardless, I want to fix it just in case. Very much appreciated by pointing it out anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Bolomeo Disregard the conversion, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Disregard the conversion to XPS or PDF file. Instead, you can transform your `UserControl` into a [FixedDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and directly print it with [PrintDialog.PrintDocument()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printdocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0); But still, any use of `PrintDialog` will block the UI.</s>

The solution is to create a `Thread` inside your `await/Task` and set its apartment state into [STA (single-threaded apartment)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stathreadattribute?view=net-6.0).

Here is a more detailed example.

```
private async void Print(){
    await Task.Run(()=>{
        // Create a thread within task and set single-threaded apartment state to avoid blocking the UI.
        Thread newThread = new(() =>{
            
            PrintLayout controlToPrint = new(){ //I don't know how you use your UserControl PrintLayout or set it's DataContext but you can do it like this;
                DataContext = YourViewModel
            };

            FixedDocument fixedDocument = new();
            //fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(YourOutputWith, YourOutputHeight); //you can set the size here, the value should be double.

            FixedPage fixedPage = new();
            fixedPage.Children.Add(controlToPrint); //Add your UserControl into FixedPage
            fixedPage.Width = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width; //Make your FixPage size same as FixedDocument.
            fixedPage.Height = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height; //Make your FixPage size same as FixedDocument.

            PageContent pageContent = new();
            ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage); //You can add more if you want.

            fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent); //Finally add the PageContent into your FixedDocument which contain your UserControl

            var printerName = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultPrinterName; //The Name of the Printer is stored on the Properties Settings.
            PrintDialog pd = new(){
                PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), printerName)
            };

            pd.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 1; //set the number of copies
            pd.PrintDocument(fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Print Job Description"); //Print it
        });

        // Set the thread to single-threaded apartment state.
        newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        // Start the thread.
        newThread.Start();

        // Wait for thread completion. Blocks the calling thread,
        // which is a ThreadPool thread.
        newThread.Join();
    });
}
```

You may also use your original code using the [PrintDialog.PrintVisual()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), just move it inside a thread with a `single-threaded apartment` to avoid blocking the UI.

Forget the [PrintDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.printdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [STA (Single-Threaded-Apartment)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stathreadattribute?view=net-6.0). For performance reasons, and much better approach, it is recommended to use either of [AddJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.addjob?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter.write?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)/[WriteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter.writeasync?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of [XpsDocumentWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Here is an example of using WriteAsync of XpsDocumentWriter to avoid blocking the UI on print.

```
private void Print(){
    
    PrintLayout controlToPrint = new(){ //I don't know how you use your UserControl PrintLayout or set it's DataContext but you can do it like this;
        DataContext = YourViewModel
    };

    FixedDocument fixedDocument = new();
    //fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(YourOutputWith, YourOutputHeight); //you can set the size here, the value should be double.

    FixedPage fixedPage = new();
    fixedPage.Children.Add(controlToPrint); //Add your UserControl into FixedPage
    fixedPage.Width = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width; //Make your FixPage size same as FixedDocument.
    fixedPage.Height = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height; //Make your FixPage size same as FixedDocument.

    PageContent pageContent = new();
    ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage); //You can add more if you want.

    fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent); //Finally add the PageContent into your FixedDocument which contain your UserControl

    var printerName = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultPrinterName; //The Name of the Printer is stored on the Properties Settings.
    PrintQueue printQueue = new(new PrintServer(), printerName); //create a new PrintQueue with the selected printer
    PrintTicket printTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket; //get the default PrintTicket, you can use this to define the settings of a print job, for example, setting the number of copies to print.
    printTicket.CopyCount = 1; //Set the number of copies.
    
    XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue); //create a new XpsDocumentWriter for print queue
    
    void OnPrintCompleted(object sender, WritingCompletedEventArgs e){ //trigger this method once the print is completed.
        Trace.WriteLine("Printing Done.");
        xpsDocumentWriter.WritingCompleted -= OnPrintCompleted; //always unregistered this event when done to avoid a potential memory leak.
    }
    xpsDocumentWriter.WritingCompleted += OnPrintCompleted; //handled the event when print is completed.
    //xpsDocumentWriter.WritingCancelled += OnWritingCancelled; //you can also handle the event when print is cancelled. PrintProgress is also possible.
    
    xpsDocumentWriter.WriteAsync(fixedDocument, printTicket); //print async without blocking the UI.
 }
```

Refer to the documentation of [XpsDocumentWriter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for more information.

Comment: This gives me an error of `System.NotSupportedException: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.`. This is probably because I'm setting the `DataContext` of the `PrintLayout` inside the thread which is of course a separate thread. I tried to use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` with no luck.

Comment: I see, interesting. The updated answer solves the issue with the collection, and it's pretty fast. Doesn't consume too much memory and CPU.